# creating dynamic page URLs with CI (routing) - a simple message board example

Tags: php, codeigniter

I feel like I have enough experience with CI to finally start fooling around with creating a message board... Or at least thats what I thought, until I got stuck at generating dynamic pages based on subject names (slugs).

So, I creating the controller/model/views and set up a form that submits the necessary info to the database.  I pulled the threads out and display them, and generate a link for each one based on the subject title...i essentially followed the CI tutorial, editing it to suit my needs.

However, understanding the concept of generating dynamic page URLs is throwing me off.  I understand a lot better by hearing exactly whats happening during the process, and the codeigniter tutorial (news) doesnt explain it well. It simply tells you what to do and how, and not why.

Anyone out there feel up to attempting to explain in greater detail, the process to code dynamic pages.

What I mean by dynamic pages is :

http://your-site.com/news/1/hello-world
http://your-site.com/news/1/foo-bar

where hello world and foo bar.

Here are some parts that confuse me:

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {

    }
}
```

And heres the routing

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

what does $1 represent?  Any specific url that there?  When would you use $2? Is it built in code to CI, or can you use any variable?

I'm sure the answer can get more detailed, but If someone could answer some of the above questions, i'm sure it'd be very helpful.

With those questions answered, in theory, what should be done to produce a new page for a forum thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {

    }
}
```

The corresponding url for this method would be http://example.com/pages/view/. In the method it is set to `$page = 'home'` because if there is no third segment in the url, it will default to `home`.

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

The variable `$1` is whatever you have as your `(:any)`. So if you url is http://example.com/testing, it would route to http://example.com/pages/view/testing and that would in turn set your $page var from your view method to "testing".

Comment: Thanks, but to expand on that.  What happens when 'testing' doesn't exist as a php file.  If you want it to be created based on the thread subject.  How does CI handle situations like that?

Comment: testing will never exist as a php file. It is just a segment in the url that will be set to the $page variable. You can then query your db in your method to find the thread based on that segment.

Comment: Also, if you do `public function view($page)` rather than `public function view($page = 'home')`, it means that you MUST have a third segment, but if you set the var equal to something, it means that if the segment is not passed in the url, it will be defaulted to the value set in the method call as done in your example.

Comment: Its starting to make more sense. Thank you.  Although, I guess im still not seeing the connection between why 'testing' is related at all to $page.  Does $page inherit the segment whenever the page loads? For instance: http://site.com/view/testing:  Once loaded, $page instantly becomes 'testing'?  What makes that happen?

Comment: Read the docs again - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

Comment: So when dealing with class functions, the only variables that should ever pass into the class are uri segments?  Effectively meaning that model functions and class functions are different?

Comment: No. You can also call the view function from another function and pass in variables that way as well. For example if you had a function called "test", you could call your view function like this `$this->view($someVar);`.

Answer (score 4):

> what does $1 represent? Any specific url that there? When would you
>   use $2? Is it built in code to CI, or can you use any variable?

`$1` represents a reference to the variable created by the wildcard `(:any)`.  There is no `$2`, because you only have one wildcard.

You would have a second wildcard if you created a route like this:

```
$route['pages/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'pages/$1/$2';
```

With that said, the route setup within your question kind of defeats the purpose of CI's MVC architecture and route system, as you're redirecting ALL routes to `pages/views`, I'm fairly sure you want something like:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['pages/view/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Comment: Thank you, but as asked in the above answer, how does CI handle views based on a URL that is dynamically created through fetched data?